# Unable to get the Onesignal userid when the user install the app first time in Flutter

Tags: flutter, onesignal

I want to store the onesignal User Id in the database when the user install my app first time. I wrote the following code which is not allowing me to do so.

However when the user Logged out from the app and re-login then I am able to retrieve the onesignal user ID and able to save in the Database.

```
 Future<void> initPlatformState(username) async {
             
              if (!mounted) return;
          
              OneSignal.shared.setLogLevel(OSLogLevel.verbose, OSLogLevel.none);
          
              OneSignal.shared.setRequiresUserPrivacyConsent(_requireConsent);
          
              var settings = {
                OSiOSSettings.autoPrompt: false,
                OSiOSSettings.promptBeforeOpeningPushUrl: true
              };
                          
             
         
              OneSignal.shared
                  .setSubscriptionObserver((OSSubscriptionStateChanges changes) {
                      
               print("SUBSCRIPTION STATE CHANGED: ${changes.jsonRepresentation()}");
                                
              });
              
              OneSignal.shared.setPermissionObserver((OSPermissionStateChanges changes) {
                
               print("PERMISSION STATE CHANGED: ${changes.jsonRepresentation()}");
              });
          
              OneSignal.shared.setEmailSubscriptionObserver(
                  (OSEmailSubscriptionStateChanges changes) {
                print("EMAIL SUBSCRIPTION STATE CHANGED ${changes.jsonRepresentation()}");
              });
          
              await OneSignal.shared
                  .init("MY Onesignal APP ID", iOSSettings: settings);
          
              OneSignal.shared
                  .setInFocusDisplayType(OSNotificationDisplayType.notification);

           var status = await OneSignal.shared.getPermissionSubscriptionState();

                onesignalUserId = status.subscriptionStatus.userId;   
       
          print("player ID: "+ onesignalUserId.toString()); // printing only in re-login
          _saveOneSignalId(onesignalUserId,username); // my save funtion into the DB
                    
                                         }
```

Comment: Have you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can call the below function inside your main.dart file when initialising the One Signal to get playerId/userId. The below function is called when user opend the app for first time or when the userId (playerId) changes.

```
OneSignal.shared.setSubscriptionObserver((OSSubscriptionStateChanges changes) async {
     String onesignalUserId = changes.to.userId;
     print('Player ID: ' + onesignalUserId);
}
```

The playerId/userId can be used to send test notification or notifications to particular user.

Comment: This works for both Android and iOS

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
OneSignal.shared.setSubscriptionObserver((OSSubscriptionStateChanges changes) 
 async{
 var status = await OneSignal.shared.getPermissionSubscriptionState();
 if (status.subscriptionStatus.subscribed){
 String onesignalUserId = status.subscriptionStatus.userId;
 print('Player ID: ' + onesignalUserId);
}
```